# Mat paginator items per page not working in angular 9

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular9, mat-pagination

I'm rendering the table data from an observable and then assigning the datasource to the paginator. The next page arrows are working, as well as the first page and last page buttons.
When I'm trying to change the items per page, it is not working. I tried ngAfterViewInit and page event calling and they did'nt make any difference.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataserviceService } from 'src/app/dataservice.service';
import { DataProvider } from 'src/app/services/dataprovider';
import { MatSort, MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { SamastaDigitalPayDataModel } from 'src/app/services/model.interface';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mis-dig-pay-report',
  templateUrl: './mis-dig-pay-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mis-dig-pay-report.component.css']
})
export class MisDigPayReportComponent implements OnInit  {

  showTable: boolean;
  choosenValue;
  dataSource;
  optionType: number;
  getby: string;
  date;
  maxDate: Object = new Date();
  blob: Blob;
  isClicked1: boolean = false;
  isClicked2: boolean = false;
  length;
  

  constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe, private service: DataserviceService, public dataProvider: DataProvider)  { }
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

       
  displayedColumns = ["merchantName", "superMerchantName", "branchName","branchLoginId","fingpayTxnId","requestMethod", "requestBranchId", "requestAccountId", "requestLoanSeries", "requestStatus", "requestTimestamp","aadharNumber","upiId","cardScheme","cardNumber", "customerPhoneNumber","statusMessage","latitude","longitude","deviceImei","remarks","referenceId","orderId","terminalId"];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.getTableData();
    // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
  
 


  getDisplayedColumns() {
    return this.displayedColumns;
  }

  getTableData() {
    console.log(this.datepipe.transform(this.date[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

    console.log(this.datepipe.transform(this.date[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
    console.log("option",this.optionType)


    this.showTable= true;
    this.service.getMisDigitalPayments(this.datepipe.transform(this.date[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd'), this.datepipe.transform(this.date[1], 'yyyy-MM-dd') ).subscribe(

    response => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<SamastaDigitalPayDataModel>(response["data"]);
        this.length = response["data"].length;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        console.log("table data",response["data"])
        console.log("choosen", this.choosenValue)
      }, 
      )
  }
  pageEvent(event){
    //it will run everytime you change paginator
    console.log("event")
      this.getTableData();
  }

  


 
  // downloadReport() {
  //   console.log("downloading")
  //   this.service.getDownloadBalanceInquiryReport(this.datepipe.transform(this.date[0], 'yyyy-MM-dd'), this.datepipe.transform(this.date[1], 'yyyy-MM-dd')).subscribe(response => {

  //     const blob = new Blob([response["data"]], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
  //     console.log(blob)
  //     let link = document.createElement("a");
  //     let filename = "balance" + new Date().toLocaleString() + ".csv";
  //     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  //     link.setAttribute("href", url);
  //     link.setAttribute("download",filename);
  //     link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  //     document.body.appendChild(link);
  //     link.download = filename;
  //     link.click();
  //     });
    
  // }

}
```

```html
<h3 align="center"> Payment Report</h3>
<div class="container-fluid" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <ejs-daterangepicker placeholder="From and To Date"format='dd-MM-yyyy' [max]='maxDate' [(ngModel)]="date"></ejs-daterangepicker>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <button class="btn customBtn" (click)="getTableData(); ">Get Report</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div [hidden]="!showTable">
    <div class="text-right">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input class="inputSearch" matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
   
    <div class=" col-lg-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" >
        <div class="btn-group-export" style="margin-top: 15px;">
            <button id="exportBtn1"  (click)="exporter.exportTable('csv', {fileName:'MISDigitalPaymentReport'}); isClicked1 = true; isClicked2 = false;"  [ngClass]="{'set-color-export': isClicked1 }">Export to csv</button>
            <button id="exportBtn2"  (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'MISDigitalPaymentReport'}); isClicked1 = false; isClicked2 = true;" [ngClass]="{'set-color-export': isClicked2 }">Export to xlsx</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: auto;">

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="tableCss table-striped" style="width: 100%;" matSort matTableExporter    #exporter="matTableExporter" >
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="merchantName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.merchantName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="branchName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Branch Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.branchName}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="branchLoginId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Branch Login Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.branchLoginId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="fingpayTxnId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fingpay Txn Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.fingpayTxnId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="superMerchantName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Corporate Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.superMerchantName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestMethod">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Method </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestMethod}}</td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestBranchId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header align="center"> Request Branch Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestBranchId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestAccountId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Account Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestAccountId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestLoanSeries">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Loan Series</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestLoanSeries}} </td>
        </ng-container>
    
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestStatus">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Status </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestStatus}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="requestTimestamp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Request Timestamp </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.requestTimestamp}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="aadharNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Aadhar Number </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.aadharNumber}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardAcceptorTerminalIdentification">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> cardAcceptorTerminalIdentification </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardAcceptorTerminalIdentification}} </td>
        </ng-container>
       
        <ng-container matColumnDef="upiId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> UpiId </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.upiId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardScheme">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Card Scheme </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardScheme}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="cardNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Card Number </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cardNumber}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="customerPhoneNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Customer PhoneNumber </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerPhoneNumber}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="statusMessage">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status Message </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.statusMessage}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="latitude">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Latitude </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.latitude}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="longitude">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Longitude </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.longitude}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceImei">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Device Imei </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.deviceImei}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="remarks">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Remarks </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.remarks}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="referenceId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Reference Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.referenceId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="orderId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Order Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.orderId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="terminalId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Terminal Id </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.terminalId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
       
    
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:   getDisplayedColumns();"></tr>
    
    </table>
    </div>

    </div>
    <mat-paginator  #paginator  [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to link the `page` event on `mat-paginator`

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25]" [pageSize]="query.pageSize"
            (page)="onPaginateChange($event)"></mat-paginator>
```

On your .ts file

```
 onPaginateChange($event) {
 console.log($event);
 }
```

Try to call your function in this method and check.

Comment: It says:Cannot read property 'pageSize' of undefined

Comment: You don't have to copy entire thing. just focus on `(page)` function.

Comment: yeah, with the page function, it is not being called on changing the items per page

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz demo?

Comment: The problem seems to be happening in my local for some reason, i'm using angular 9. It's working on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error in the core.js file for some unknown reason. To resolve the issue, I have updated my project to the latest version angular 10 using the commands:

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
ng update @angular/material
```